# My html script wont work when im using setTimeout();

Tags: html, settimeout

i am verry new to HTML and im trying to make a simple website. my code works fine but when i use the setTimeout(); funktion my code dosent relly work. The next function just wont start when im using this line:
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ("du har: "+s+" ved klabbar");
i think the veriabel dosent transfer to the next funktion. The problem is i dont know how to be able to use the veribl in the next functin. Iv trid googleing alot but i dont find any way to do whant i want to do. Theefor i turn to stack oveflow.
here is all of my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <style>
    #loader {
    border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite; /* Safari */
    animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
    }

    /* Safari */
    @-webkit-keyframes spin {
    0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }
    }

    @keyframes spin {
    0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>



    </body>
    </html>
    
    
    <h1>Exakt hur mycket ved har du hemma?</h1>

    <label for="quantity" id="lab">Skriv in mängd ved:</label>
    <input type="text" id="qua" name="quantity"> 
    <button onclick="myFunction()" id=bttn>räkna</button>
    <div id="loader"></div>
    <h1 id="txt">Räknar...</h1>

    <script>
    document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("txt").style.display = "none";

    </script>

    <p id="demo"></p>


    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script>
    function myFunction() {
    var s= document.getElementById("qua").value;
    document.getElementById("lab").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("bttn").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("qua").style.display = "none";
    document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "block";
    document.getElementById("txt").style.display = "block";

    const myTimeout = setTimeout(myGreeting, 5000);
    }
    function myGreeting() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = ("du har: "+s+" ved klabbar");

    document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "none";

    }
    </script>






    </body>
    </html>
```

does annyone know how to solv my problem please write. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to add "return s" at `myFunction()`. the syntax will be like this.

```js
 function myFunction() {
        var s = document.getElementById("qua").value;
        document.getElementById("lab").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("bttn").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("qua").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("txt").style.display = "block";
        const myTimeout = setTimeout(myGreeting, 5000);

        return s;
    }
```

and for `myGreetings()` function, you must call the `myFunction()` .

```js
function myGreeting() {
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "du har: " + myFunction() +" ved klabbar"
            document.getElementById("loader").style.display = "none";
    }
```

i hope this will help you :)